# How to split a decision tree on a column's value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to solve a problem and I'm unable to get through this phase.

I'm working on the 'Breast cancer' dataset.

#### First, consider building a simple, one-level decision tree to classify tumors as benign or malignant.

Consider the following two potential splits

- Splitting on radius worst at 16.8
- Splitting on radius worst at 19.8

For each of these splits, calculate the resulting mean squared error. What is the mean squared error
impurity of the dataset with no split? (Note: if you’re wondering about the appropriateness of using
the mean-squared-error on binary outcomes, see the optional handout on binary decision trees in your
course handout).
Based on these results, which of these two splits is best?

### I'm done with the rest of the question, just trying to figure out how to split decision tree on a column's value.

I think it has something to do with the (splitter=) parameter of decision tree classifier model. Can anyone help me out?

#### Code

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as dt


model = dt(max_depth=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: you forgot to include the question

Comment: @NicolasGervais Just updated!

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the question, long time I see but better now than never.
You just cannot do this using *sklearn* framework. In sklearn you just can select the method that will be used to select the variables for the split (select the method, not the variables you want) and the criterion to perform the split on variables (again, the criterion to be used, not the value you want to split for).

So you just cannot do that. The only thing I can think of if you want to use just a column is to use a X dataframe with only that column, and in order to have an split for an specific value, you can create a new column with 1s and 0s by splitting for the value you wanted and use that column in the decision tree.

i.e. if a column is "column1" = [1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 8], and I want to split by value 4, you can create "column1_split" = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], putting 1 when the split is correct and 0 when it is not.

Hope it helps.